# Im getting an object is undefined error in react native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using drawer navigation with react navigation v5, and i have a screen called profile, that takes in a route prop, that i pass user id to. Problem is, when I visit a profile, and then logout, and log back in, i get an error saying that route.params.id is not an object, undefined. In my profile.tsx I checked where i use the route params, and its as in the shown code below:

```
      useEffect(() => {
    if (!route) {
      return navigation.navigate("Søg Brugere");
    }
    getUser();
  }, [route]);
```

and getUser function should not be executed, however I include it for clarlity.

```
  const getUser = async () => {
    if (!route) return;
    try {
      console.log(route.params.id);
      const id = route.params.id;
      setRefreshing(true);
      const { data } = await (await HttpClient()).get(
        config.SERVER_URL + "/api/user/get-user-by-id/" + id
      );
      setRefreshing(false);
      setProfile(data.user);
      setMatch(data.match);
      setInitiated(true);

      if (socket && user) {
        const notificationData = {
          url: `/profile/${user._id}`,
          type: "new-visit",
          text: `Nyt besøg fra ${user.displayName}`,
          user: data.user,
          resourceId: user._id,
        };

        socket.emit("notification", notificationData);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      navigation.navigate("Søg Brugere");
    }
  };
```

and also a snippet of my logout function, used in drawer navigator:

```
     <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "flex-end" }}>
          <Button
            onPress={async () => {
              props.navigation.replace("Søg Brugere");
              props.navigation.closeDrawer();
              await AsyncStorage.removeItem("token");
              setUser(null);
            }}
            title="Log Ud"
            color="#F44336"
          />
        </View>
```

Comment: anyone? i cant seem to fix this

Answer (score 0):

i solved this by adding at the top of my rfc:

```
const id = route?.params?.id
```